# Use SUM of colum values condition in select query with another condition

Tags: mysql

I have a table called stock.It have columns named as `item_id`, `'qty'` and `'branch_id'`.
what i need do is select item ids which the sum of 'qty' column grater than zero and branch_id equal to 4.

I have try with this query but I need only to view `item_id column`. This prints `total` column too.

```
SELECT `item_id`, SUM(`qty`) as total from `stock` 
group by `item_id` HAVING total > 0 and where branch_id = 4
```

help please.

Comment: `select item_id, SUM(qty) as total from stock where branch_id = 4 group by item_id HAVING total > 0`

Comment: I need only to view item_id column. This prints total column too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this query with [GROUP BY Clause](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-group-by-clause.htm) and [HAVING](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html)

```
Select b.item_id from (
select item_id, SUM(qty) as total from stock
where branch_id = 4 
group by item_id 
HAVING total > 0
) as b
```

or this query:

```
 SELECT item_id FROM stock 
 WHERE branch_id = 4
 GROUP BY item_id 
 HAVING SUM(qty) > 0
```

Comment: I need only item_id column to view..

Comment: @RandikaPerera now it works ?

Answer (score -1):

Try This

```
SELECT `item_id` FROM `stock` 
WHERE branch_id = 4
GROUP BY`item_id` HAVING SUM(`qty`) > 0;
```

`GROUP BY` awlays come after `WHERE` clause

Comment: thnks Its working but i need only to view item_id. How can i do that..?